# Junit create tests based on dynamic data

Tags: java, junit

I need to create a testsuite, with subsuites containing tests that check data for me (using a java library). The goal of it is to test if the library works ok. Think of it like a virus scanner definitions check.
I have experience with the old Junit/Nunit, and expected it to be quite easy. However, it turns out it is not with Junit4.

I have the following filesystem layout:

```
typename(dir)
    - file1
    - file2
typename(dir)
    - file1
    - file2
    - file3
etc.
```

I need to run a unittest that tests each file, and lives in a "typename" testsuite. The idea is to process the filesystem and then generate the testcases and suites dynamically:

```
for (File typeNameDir: typenameDirs)
{
  TestSuite typenameSuite= new TestSuite();
  typenameSuite.setName(typename);
  for (File file: filesInThisDir)
  {
     typenameSuite.addTest(new FileTest(File));
  }
}
```

Problem now is that `addTest` expect a class that implements `Test`, but that is an interface of the framework and not usable, because of the low level methods it needs to have implemented. I also tried to extend `TestCase` but this also doesn't work: I need to set the testname there manually and it still doesn't run normally. Also it is discouraged to extends the `junit.framework` classes.

So, it looks like I need to use `Parameterized` option, but that doesn't allow me to input dynamically generated data... So what should I do?

I am thinking of just moving to Junit 3.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at this [post](http://tedyoung.me/2011/01/22/junit-runtime-tests-overview/). The author describe a solution to generate test case at runtime.

And just for curiosity, why @Parameterized doesn't allow you to input dynamically generated data? It doesn't work like this?

```
@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
          List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
          //load files
          for (File file: filesInThisDir) {
               data.add(file);
          }

          return data;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but since this method is `static` I can't supply that method with for example the dynamic path where it needs to get it's files.

Comment: @Peterdk JUnit need to know how many test cases will be run before it executes any of them, so the method is static. Could you given an dynamic path example? I'm sorry I don't get it.

Comment: As seen in the startpost, I need a seperate testsuite for every typename folder. So the parametrized test needs to know which folder it needs: `filesInThisDir` needs to receive somehow dynamically the filepath. That can't be done.