# Running a test method multiple times without using loop

Tags: java, rest-assured

The scenario is like i will fetch four data from open api end points from a json array for the first thre`enter code here`e output. Then i kept the data in four arraylist, account no, com amount, revenue amount, mark up realized amount. Till this it works fine. Now i have to take the first index data from each of the list and use it in a test method. In this whay i would take the secound index, third indexx data from array list and use it in the sme test method. The test method will go the ui and vaidate. I have right now used a loop which executes this test method three times by taking data three times from the arraylist. Is there a different way where i can avoid the loop in test method and the test method will execute three times by taking the each index value from the arraylist.

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods = "getTransactionRecordDetailsForSpecificAccountNumberByDateRange")

public void verifyTransactionDetailsFromOpenAPIOnSFObject() throws InterruptedException, AWTException {enter code here

    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        
        launchApp();
        homepage = new HomePage();
        companyaccountpage = new CompanyAccountPage();
        homepage.navigateToCompanyAccountDetailsPage(li_AcctNo.get(i));
        companyaccountpage.navigateToTransactionTableDetails();
        Assert.assertEquals(companyaccountpage.getValueOfTotalComissionAmountFromTransactionTable(actual_tsDate),
                li_comAmt.get(i));
        Assert.assertEquals(companyaccountpage.getValueOfTotalMarkUpRealizedAmountTransactionTable(actual_tsDate),
                li_markupAmt.get(i));
        Assert.assertEquals(companyaccountpage.getValueOfTotalRevenueAmountFromTransactionTable(actual_tsDate),
                li_revenueAmt.get(i));`enter code here`
        fd.quit();
```

Comment: Have a look at JUnit parametrized tests (depending on whether you use JUnit 4 or 5).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Junit create tests based on dynamic data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699959/junit-create-tests-based-on-dynamic-data)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps three different test cases would be another way to do things logically too since you're testing for different details. If you're worried about code duplication, then you can make a separate function for the loop logic.